# Django form not displaying name and email fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to learn how to use the User class and have made a form, but cant get it to display the email, first_name and last_name fields, I have the following code:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name'
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

    def save(self, commit = True):
        user super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name =  self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email =  self.cleaned_data['email']

            if commit:
                user.save()

                return user
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('index page')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('accounts')

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
# Create your views here.
```

register.html:

```
{%  extends 'accounts/base.html' %}

{% block head %}
    <title> Sign Up</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>

  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I go to /accounts/register a form with username, password and password confirmation fields appear and the form works and saves to the database. But where are the `first_name`, `last_name`, `email` fields inlcuded in the  `User` model?

Comment: You aren't using your RegistrationForm anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use `RegistrationForm` instead of `UserCreationForm` in your views

replace

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

to

```
from .forms import RegistrationForm

form = RegistrationForm()
```